# Enable Intel Vt-x (Intel Virtualization Technology, Intel VT-x)

Tags: android

While I was trying to install android studio i got above error of vt-x.
please tell me how to enable vt-x in windows 10
[above image shows the error][1]
        [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB3wk.png

Answer (score 1):

Please note that this how nothing to do with windows 10, its an option in your bios

1. Power on the machine and open the BIOS
2. Open the Processor submenu The processor settings menu may be hidden in the Chipset, Advanced CPU Configuration or Northbridge.
3. Enable Intel Virtualization Technology (also known as Intel VT)

Furthermore the exact same answer can be found with a simple google search and this is not a programming question either.

Answer (score 0):

For Installing android studio you need to enable Virtualization Technology (VT-X) in BIOS of computer.
You can enter in BIOS when your computer in boot mode by pressing F2 or F8 or F2 etc. etc. actually it's depends on vendor of motherboard.

[Sample Image of BIOS used for enable virtualization](http://cdn.sysprobs.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/virt_bios.gif)